# how to insert a hashMap into excel to draw a graph

Tags: java, excel, graph, hashmap

I have a hashMap in java in terms of some keys which each key is indicating a flow. Then each value showing statics about each packet belongs to that flow.

What I need to do is, to draw graphs for each flow based on those values. 
for example:

```
Flow1: {[length, time],[],[],...}
Flow2: {[length, time],[length, time],[],...}
```

I need to plot them in Excel. Can anyone has the idea to give me some clues please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) ?

Or the [Java bindings](http://udk.openoffice.org/java/man/index.html) for the Openoffice UNO ? (you run an instance of Openoffice and control it using Java)